# Linux Ubuntu Desktop vs Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to host a Webserver on my PC mainly to run Wordpress on it. But I am going to use VMWare Workstation for running it along with Windows.

Now, what I'd like to know, do I need **Ubuntu Server** to host the site or can I use **Ubuntu Desktop** for the Job?. Note that the server is not for high traffic, is mainly for testing by myself and maybe a few other people...

Thank you

Comment: Your question is off-topic see the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: thank you. I suspected so, but gave it a shot anyways. Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu Desktop can handle the job just fine, you'll just have to install a web server, an SQL server, etc., via aptitude. The main [difference between Desktop and Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F) is that Server comes without GUI and other 'features' -- thus if you want to run a more lightweight instance, Server might be favorable.

Comment: Cool, thank you man! So how does this aptitude work? Is it a program, API or what? I am completely new to Linux

Comment: @DextrousDave You're welcome! 

Aptitude is Ubuntu's package manager. It's one of the best things about Linux (most distros come with some form of package manager), and it allows you to install and maintain a ton of software through a simple, uniform interface. For example, to install apache2, php5, and mysql (the prerequisites for WP), you'd go:

    `sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql php5-mysql`

There's also a very easy to use GUI in the Desktop version; I'd advise you to use this as you're new to the Linux world. :) It's called "Software Center," I believe.

Answer (score 3):

They are slightly different, but one can be converted to another without reinstall.

Server comes with some packages like apache preinstalled, but no GUI.
Desktop comes with GUI and office-related packages like LibreOffice preinstalled.

Server has server kernel which is in package `linux-image-server`, and desktop has desktop kernel `linux-image-generic`.

You can convert for example desktop into server by executing

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-server
```

and then you need to tweak grub.cfg such that new kernel is booted by default.

Biggest difference for server kernel is that it gives less priority to interactive tasks and more to serving background server tasks.

Comment: thank you. appreciate your answer

Comment: Since 12.04, there is no difference in kernel between desktop and server

Comment: Correct. But it is still good to know how to convert workstation to server or back if you happen to stumble across some old Linux server. Not everybody upgraded to 12.04 yet.